# SCP from ssh remote machine to my local ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, ssh, scp

I am trying to scp some files from a remote machine to my local ubuntu 16.04 machine. However, I am getting error with the port and network. my machine name is trina and I am trying

```
$ scp -r Slice_z_density/ trina@10.0.0.10:~/
```

this returns me :

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.10 port 22: Network is unreachable
lost connection
```

I wonder if I am writing the right IP address, when I go to network settings: I find the following info for my wireless connection:

```
IPv4 Address: 10.0.0.10
IPv6 Address: 2601:192:8802:d9d0:5905:d7f:7320:9c18
Default route: 10.0.0.1
```

I tried all 3 of these and still getting same error. your help is appreciated and thanks

Comment: Do you actually have an SSH/SCP server installed and configured on the local machine? if not, you will need to "pull" the files from the server using an scp client on the local side

Comment: What is the IP of your remote machine ? Can you ping 10.0.0.10 from your remote machine ? Is your machine in your home and your remote machine is somewhere else ?

Comment: @steeldriver can you please tell me how do I check if ssh/scp server installed or not in my machine? I go to that remote machine by: ssh username@stampede.tacc.utexas.edu and enetr password and token, and it connects me there

Comment: @hatterman, the remote machine is the stampede supercomputer at austin, my machine is at home. I don't know how to find IP of stampede though, can you tell me?

Comment: Doesn't mater at this stage. So, your home PC is attached to your home router I guess. (It must be). So, you will not be able to connect to your home PC directly. You need to set up port forwarding on your home router and connect to that from your remote machine in Austin. I'll write something in an answer to help you.

Comment: ... it will be FAR simpler to "pull" the files from the local side

Comment: ... if the remote side allows him to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your home router, you need to set up port forwarding. Forward some port number (say 7022) to port 22 on your home PC 10.0.0.10.

Now, you need to find the IP address of your home router. Easiest way is to go to [www.whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org).

Presuming your remote location in Austin allows you to SCP out of the facility (you would have to speak to the network admins there) and assuming your SSH server is up and running on your home PC and configured to use port 22, you would do ;

```
scp -r Slice_z_density/ trina@<your router IP> -P 7022
```

assuming your router IP is 151.12.34.123

```
scp -r Slice_z_density/ trina@151.12.34.123 -P 7022
```

The port forwarding on your router will redirect your connection to your home PC.

I connect this way all the time from my office PC to my home PC, but I had to talk with the sys admin guys and get them to allow me to connect to a few ports on my home router (so they configured the office firewall accordingly). You will probably have to get them to allow port 7022 from your home network at their end.

Seeing as you can connect to your remote machine via ssh, then as suggested you should also be able to 'pull' the file from the remote machine, so you perform the scp operation from your own home machine;

```
scp username@stampede.tacc.utexas.edu:/file/to/copy  /location/to/save
```

eg

```
scp username@stampede.tacc.utexas.edu:/file/to/copy  /home/myname/Desktop/
```